# Question about reflexive spaces in Brezis' functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

**Theorem 2.16.** *Let $G$ and $L$ be two closed subspaces in a Banach space E. The following properties are equivalent:*

(a) *$G+L$ is closed in $E$,*

(b) *$G^\perp+L^\perp$ is closed in $E^*$,*

(c) *$G+L=(G^\perp\cap L^\perp)^\perp$,*

(d) *$G^\perp+L^\perp=(G\cap L)^\perp$.*

Show that the proof of Theorem 2.16 becomes much easier if $E$ is reflexive. Find, in particular, a simple proof of (b) $\Rightarrow$ (a).

How do the condition that "E is reflexive" work here?

Comment: If you know (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b) you can just apply this  to $G^\perp$ and $L^\perp$ to get that $G+L= G^{\perp\perp} + L^{\perp\perp} $ is closed in $E^{**}=E$.